# Popup view goes back to initial SKScene instead of current SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, skscene

I have two SKScenes that are called StartMenu, GameMenu and I have created a popup view (AddSubView) to be added inside GameMenu.

My problem is that whenever I call the function that runs the popupview, it goes back to the initial SKScene - StartMenu instead of the current SKScene GameMenu.

code:

```
            var v :UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
            v.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            self.scene?.view?.addSubview(v)
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Added the code, its just a short visual display to represent the popup view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to avoid using subViews for SpriteKit as according to Apple, it is best to create Popup menus using SKSpriteNode and SKNodes.